# Directory has suddenly become read-only while running PhotoRec, why?

Tags: data-recovery, read-only, testdisk

I've spent the past four hours running PhotoRec on my Ubuntu machine to recover some pngs images on my 750GB drive, with the recovered files being saved to a 2GB drive. Needless to say, I was deleting the recovered files as they were coming. However, for reasons that I cannot fathom, after about 7,000 files, the 2GB drive suddenly became read-only and due to the inability that this gave me to delete the recovered files, the drive eventually become full and PhotoRec had stopped. This has lead me to three questions:

1) Most importantly, why has this happened?

2) Without unmouting the drive, how can I make these files not read-only and therefore deletable?

3) Once I have done this, how can I resume PhotoRec?

Comment: Could be due to a hardware error.: pen drives sometimes become read only when EOL.

Comment: Are you saying that I should unmount the drive and check? I'll admit that your comment has greatly tempted me to do so, but that would probably render point #3 on my list impossible, as I'd likely have to kill the PhotoRec process in order to unmount the drive.

Comment: I'll be off to bed soon, which of course means turning off my computer and hence unmounting the drive. So I'll just unmount it now and report the result... upon remounting the drive, I am now getting the follow error: "This location could not be displayed. Sorry, could not display all the contents of “2CCA-BCF0”: Error when getting information for file '/media/[my name]/2CCA-BCF0/System Volume Information': Input/output error". Does this suggest that you're right? I'll check it in another machine ASAP.

Comment: Plugged USB into a Mac and it worked just fine. It's now started working again on my Ubuntu machine, so that's hardware errors ruled out.

Comment: Not really... you got an I/O error, which is almost certainly due to a hardware fault.  Check syslog or `dmesg` for more detailed error information.